# Installing live drupal website in local

Tags: theming

I am trying to install my live drupal (version 8) website in localhost. I have downloaded the files and folders. I have imported the database. And updated settings.php file.

But when I try to log in, after entering username and password, the page redirects to core/install.php and I get this message - "Drupal already installed".

what does this mean? How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Hey Suja, welcome to Drupal Answers. We love to help you. And we need more info about your setup. OS? Composer? Under what URL do you access the site locally? First wild guess would be to check your `.htaccess` that `RewriteBase /` is set.

Comment: @leymannx Thanks...My OS is Windows-10..I am using XAMPP v3.3.2 (PHP Version 7.0.32).
URL is http://localhost:8080/MyTestSite/testsite.com/ and the login URL is http://localhost:8080/MyTestSite/testsite.com/user/login......  
After log in, after entering username and password, page redirects to http://localhost:8080/MyTestSite/testsite.com/core/install.php.... In .htaccess, I can see this: 
  # RewriteBase /drupal
...Should I edit here?

Comment: `# RewriteBase /drupal` should become `RewriteBase /MyTestSite/testsite.com` (yes, without the `#` at the beginning).

Comment: @leymannx I have modified RewriteBase, restarted XAMPP, cleared browser cache, but still, the page redirects to core/install.php

Comment: "I have imported the database." What database, and from where?

Comment: @Free Radical database from a live drupal website

Comment: What happens if you click the link to view your *existing site* (the last bullet point on the error message you reproduce)?

Answer (score 1):

This error message is shown when you try to install Drupal, but the Drupal install script detects that there is already a *populated* (i.e. not empty) database present in the database pointed to by `settings.php`.

Here is how you set up an empty database to hold Drupal (provided the database is named "drupal").

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Password:
mysql> DROP DATEBASE drupal;
mysql> CREATE DATABASE drupal;
mysql> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO drupal@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER,
    -> LOCK TABLES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON drupal.* TO drupal@localhost
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> quit
Bye
$
```

This will create an empty database named "drupal", belonging to a database user named "drupal", with the passord "password". (Choose a more obscure password than "password".)

Then delete `settings.php` and copy `default.settings.php` to `settings.php`.  Do *not* edit it. Make sure the directory where `settings.php` lives and `settings.php` itself is writable by the web server.  That will make the install script create a new `settings.php` with the correct values during the install.

After doing all this: Start again installing Drupal.

After installation is complete, change the permissions for `settings.php` and its directory back to safe values.  Check that there are no warnings in the Drupal status report.

Comment: thank you....I am trying to recreate a live drupal website locally.....I have imported the live website's database locally...downloaded the live website's files and folders...

Comment: If I delete settings.php, it will be like a fresh drupal installation..I need my live website's database..

Comment: @Suja – He just wants you to run the default installation. To ensure everything gets created properly. And when this is done, simply drop the database `drush sql-drop -y` and import your live database `drush sql-cli < /path/to/live/db/dump.sql`.

Comment: I've tried this. Still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Drupal installation has detected an existing installation using active configuration on settings.php.

The easiest way to get rid of this error is to replace settings.php under sites/default/ directory with content from default.settings.php file.

Comment: Thanks. I did this. But after importing database from the live server, I get the same 'Drupal already installed' message.

Comment: @Suja,  Drupal creates a unique UUID for each installation. If you have Drush installed on both machine try to check if both UUIDs are the same.  
In order to get uuid using Drush run this command.   
`drush config-get "system.site" uuid`  
And you can set uuid value using Drush by running   
`drush config-set "system.site" uuid 'uuid value'`
This is rarely the issue as you are actually importing the database from your production site. 

Also, make sure to clear cache once you complete import the database to your localhost.